# Grep command search

Tags: linux

Hi i have a folder which it has a lot of files..
I would like to know which file contains the number e.g. 980398123. I am in Putty and i have cd  to the path containing those files.. So how do i search it using Grep.

```
grep 980398123 "waht to put here"
```

Since I am search all the files, there will be no file name .. so waht should i put there?

Also, is there a way for me to search in within the time frame? Let say i want to grep those files contains the word within a date range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need the `find` command to recursively go through the directories, e.g. your current directory '.'

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l 980398123 {} \;
```

you can also use regular expressions in your grep command to search for date ranges

See:

`man find` , 
 `man grep`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried yours, "find . -type f -exec grep -l 980398123 {} \;" , But it throws Missing argument to '-exec'

Answer (score 0):

What about `*` ? If you want to make the recursive seach, you need to add the `-r` option. So, your comand would be like this: `grep -r "980398123" *`

Comment: I tried yours.. but it said "Arguement list too long" .. failed to search